# WordPress pagination won't show more then 2 pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress, pagination, categories

I am working on a category page which will show all the posts of the current category.

I have tried multiple things to show the pagination, but with my code it will only show 2 pages and not more while there are 14 posts in the category. This is my code:

```
<?php
$currentPage = get_query_var('paged');

$args_overview = array(
    'post_type' => 'nieuws',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'categorie' => get_queried_object()->slug,
    'paged' => $currentPage
);
$posts_overview = get_posts($args_overview);
?>
```

```
                    <div class="wpb-category__filter-posts">
                        <?php
                        if (have_posts()) :
                        ?>
                            <?php foreach ($posts_overview as $post) :
                            ?>
                                <div href="#" class="wpb-category__post-item">
                                    <div class="wpb-category__post-item-top">
                                        <a href="<?= get_permalink(); ?>">
                                            <?= wpb_image(get_field('algemeen', $post)['afbeelding'], 'auto', 'auto') ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="wpb-category__post-item-bottom">
                                        <strong><?= $post->post_title ?></strong>
                                        <a href="<?= get_permalink(); ?>">
                                            <p>Lees meer</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php endforeach;
                            wp_reset_postdata();
                            echo "<div class='page-nav-container'>" . paginate_links(array(
                                // 'total' => $posts_overview->max_num_pages, (I thought this will show all available pages, but it just removes the whole pagination)
                                'prev_text' => __('<'),
                                'next_text' => __('>')
                            )) . "</div>";

                            ?>
                        </div>
```

The code shows all the posts, but only 2 pages.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `get_posts` returns just an array of posts - so there is no `$posts_overview->max_num_pages` to access here. You need to use `WP_Query` to get your posts, _then_ you can access all of the properties that class offers: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#properties

Comment: (Your loop needs to be modified accordingly as well then. The `$posts` property of the WP_Query instance holds the current selection of posts.)

Comment: @CBroe It seems that that is working, when I am on the second page, it's now showing a button to go to the 3th page, but when I click that button, it says page not found.

Comment: What do the actual URLs of those pagination links look like? If you just paginated beyond the "end" of available records, that should _not_ get you a 404 (nothing like that is implemented in the code you have shown, so you should just get an empty post list then) - so I am assuming that it is rather the links themselves, that are wrong.